# LC circuit with 2 capacitors, one charged, one uncharged

Tags: capacitor, inductor, passive-networks

I have started to learn about LC circuits, in particular in the case where the initial conditions are where the capacitor has previously been charged.

I am struggling to understand what would happen in a case where there is two capacitors and an inductor all connected in parallel, where one of the capacitors has been previously charged, and the other capacitor is uncharged. The capacitors are of equal capacitance.

I have read that you just treat the capacitors as an equivalent capacitor in parallel (2C capacitance) for determining the frequency of the circuit. But what about at the initial conditions? If just one is charged then Q=CV. But in parallel, then Q=2CV, which adds extra charge to the system.

Can anybody explain this to me or provide a link to a solution?

Comment: If they're in parallel they can't have different voltages.

Answer (score 1):

In real caps ESR loses Pd*T= \$ V^2/ESR~*~ESR(C1+C2)\$ energy on connection but if Voltage drops to 1/2 or less the total Q is not 2Q since if C1=C2 then ideally V final =1/2Vi

Answer (score 0):

What dictates the innitial conditions for charge is the ***equivalent capacitor's charge***.

Take a look at this:

[image]

Here I assumed the clockwise current direction.

As soon as the current enters the point \$A\$, it splits into 2 parts. Each capacitor will then have its own charge and current function. However, since we assume that the charge doesn't "get stuck" inside any element,
$$I_{\text{in}} = I_{\text{out}} = I$$

In such \$LC\$ circuit problems we are typically interested in \$I\$ as a function of time. For that we need to differentiate the function of charge \$q(t)\$.

**But what is \$q(t)\$ exactly?**

*It is basically the amount of charge passing through the wire's cross-section each unit of time.* And because the charge entering our two-capacitor system is equal to the charge leaving it at any instant, we can treat the system as a single component that has a charge function \$q(t)\$ assigned to it and that function is the same for an inductor and the two wires that connect the inductor to the capacitors.